# How can I align the circle and arrow to the center of the border in css?

Tags: html, css

If I click the "hit" button, the arrow should be moved to touch the circle, and change the color of the circle.

Here I want to align the circle on the left side and center, and the arrow should be on the right side and center.

```css
section {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-arrow {
  width: 90px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 49px;
  float: right;
}

.icon-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 11px;
}

.icon-arrow:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 65px;
  bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bubble App</h1>

<section>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="icon-arrow" style="display: flex; align-items: center; "></div>


  </div>

</section>

<div class="button">
  <button onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br>
</div>
```

I'm trying to align the circle and arrow to the center, but it is not working; the circle is not aligned properly, if I make changes in the circle then the position of the arrow will be changed. How can I fix the problem?

Also, how can I align the button to the right side under the border section?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind? I didn't fully understand your question so if you need more help let me know.

I added the display flex to the section because you wanted to center the elements according to this element with the border. Now the circle and arrow are centered in the border.

```css
.container{
border: 3px solid black;
height: 60vh; 
width: 90vh;   
margin: auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}

.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

.icon-arrow{
    width: 90px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.icon-arrow:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: 11px;
}

.icon-arrow:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 65px;
    bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bubble App</h1>

<section class="container">
  <div class="circle" ></div>
  <div class="icon-arrow"></div>
</section>

<div class="button">
  <button onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem :: if i click the hit button the arrow should be move and touch the circle and change the color of the circle... so i want the circle to the leftside and center and arrow to be right side and center

Comment: @Pycoder Okay. I changed the answer by replacing 'justify-content: center' to 'justify-content: space-between'. Now the space between the circle and arrow takes up the maximum width. The circle is now always at the left-side of the border and the arrow always at the right-side. Is that better?

Comment: tanks bro how can i add some space between the border and arrow and circle and border because both are touching with the border

Comment: @Pycoder You can add margin to the .circle and .icon-arrow css classes

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,I think you are asking this thing if I have understand it wrong please let me know & ask the question with some more details.

```css
.container{
border: 3px solid black;
height: 60vh; 
width: 90vh;   
margin: auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}

.circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

.icon-arrow{
    width: 90px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.icon-arrow:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: 11px;
}

.icon-arrow:before{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 65px;
    bottom: 9px;
}

.button {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bubble App</h1>

<section class="container">
  <div class="circle" ></div>
  <div class="icon-arrow"></div>
</section>

<div class="button">
  <button onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: note like this bro  if i click the hit button the arrow should be move and touch the circle and change the color of the circle... so i want the circle to the leftside  and arrow to be right side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).